# How to get x,y coordinates of extracted objects in javacv?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv

Currently I am developing image processing project and I'm using javacv to develop image processing components. I was able to extract some interesting parts of a image and now I need to read the x and y coordinates of those objects.
This is the image that I haveextracted

[image]

And I need to identify those objects and draw square around those objects. I went through some tutorials and try to identify objects using following code.

```
    IplImage img="sourceimage";
    CvSize sz = cvSize(img.width(), img.height());
    IplImage gry=cvCreateImage(sz, img.depth(), 1);
    cvCvtColor(img, gry, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvThreshold(gry, gry, 200, 250, CV_THRESH_BINARY);


    CvMemStorage mem = CvMemStorage.create();
    CvSeq contours = new CvSeq();
    CvSeq ptr = new CvSeq();
    cvFindContours(gry, mem, contours, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class) , CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

    CvRect boundbox;

    for (ptr = contours; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.h_next()) {
        boundbox = cvBoundingRect(ptr, 0);
        if(boundbox.height()>10||boundbox.height()>10){
            cvRectangle( gry, cvPoint( boundbox.x(), boundbox.y() ), cvPoint( boundbox.x() + boundbox.width(), boundbox.y() + boundbox.height()),CvScalar.BLUE, 0, 0, 0 );
            System.out.println(boundbox.x()+", "+boundbox.y());
        }
    }
    cvShowImage("contures", gry);
    cvWaitKey(0);
```

But it doesn't draw as rectangle around the objects. I would like to know whether I can use cvFindContours method to identify those objects ? Please can some one explain how to archive my objective using javacv/opencv?

Comment: So when you draw these rectangles how are they relative to the objects you have?

Comment: Why do ignore answers to your question??

Comment: @MahdeTo I need to know how to draw rectangle around these objects.

Comment: @Astor I didn't ignore those answers I'm checking those answers because I have to convert those in to javacv. However thnax 4 rply.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to go through following code and it will give answer for your question.

```
    IplImage img=cvLoadImage("pathtosourceimage");
    CvSize cvSize = cvSize(img.width(), img.height());
    IplImage gry=cvCreateImage(cvSize, img.depth(), 1);
    cvCvtColor(img, gry, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvThreshold(gry, gry, 200, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    cvAdaptiveThreshold(gry, gry, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 5);

    CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
    CvSeq contours = new CvContour(null);

    int noOfContors = cvFindContours(gry, storage, contours, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, new CvPoint(0,0));

    CvSeq ptr = new CvSeq();

    int count =1;
    CvPoint p1 = new CvPoint(0,0),p2 = new CvPoint(0,0);

    for (ptr = contours; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.h_next()) {

        CvScalar color = CvScalar.BLUE;
        CvRect sq = cvBoundingRect(ptr, 0);

            System.out.println("Contour No ="+count);
            System.out.println("X ="+ sq.x()+" Y="+ sq.y());
            System.out.println("Height ="+sq.height()+" Width ="+sq.width());
            System.out.println("");

            p1.x(sq.x());
            p2.x(sq.x()+sq.width());
            p1.y(sq.y());
            p2.y(sq.y()+sq.height());
            cvRectangle(img, p1,p2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0);
            cvDrawContours(img, ptr, color, CV_RGB(0,0,0), -1, CV_FILLED, 8, cvPoint(0,0));
            count++;

    }

    cvShowImage("contures",img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
```

This is the output that I got for your given image.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

cvFindContours is the right solution to your problem.
And I have verified that it works on your images.
[image: Here is my experiment]

You have System.out.println inside, what's the output?

cvFindContours could be tricky to use, I have wrapped it into a [more general C++ function](https://github.com/vinjn/vOpenCV/blob/master/BlobTracker.cpp#L37). Also I use a [class called vBlob](https://github.com/vinjn/vOpenCV/blob/master/Blob.h#L21) to describe an **object** cvFindContours detects. From what I see from your java code, java version API is very similar to C/C++ version. So it won't be hard to rewrite it.

ps. Astor gave the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

Did you know that `findContours` function finds **white** contours on **black** background?

Just do `bitwise_not` (or analogue in JavaCV) to your image and after this apply `findContours`. This is actually fix to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

**No need for third party libraries!** What you are looking for can be achieved in OpenCV using a technique known as [bounding box](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html):

[image]

The trick is to use [`cvFindContours()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) to retrieve the contours and then [`cvApproxPoly()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpoly) to improve the result. Notice that you'll have to invert the colors of the input image using `cvNot()` because `cvFindContours()` search for **white** contours.

- There's a nice introduction to contours in [this post](http://www.aishack.in/2010/01/an-introduction-to-contours/).
- There's a [Java demo](http://askhackeryoda.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/detect-objects.html) that implements a version of the bounding box to detect car number plates.

By the way `cvMinEnclosingCircle()` returns the center of the circle as `CvPoint2D32f`.

Comment: Did you read a code from question and actually the question itself? He already knows how to find bounding box. And how does `approxPoly` improve result in this situation? The problem is that topicstarter doesn't understand why he get 1 rectangle instead 4. And I already explained why.

Comment: @Astor, you should not argue with karlphillip, at least of courtesy, if not for a better reason. You know, you always should respect your elders. And he's the elder here, on the opencv tag ;) It's like telling Jon Skeet his code does not compile

Answer (score 2):

I m using c++ api but I think there should also be some function in javacv named drawContours or cvDrawContours which uses the output of findContours.

Comment: But output of findContours is whole image.